# Create directive in angularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to create a directive in angularJS. But it's not working. What I have done is as follow.

my main html code

```
<body ng-app="birthdayToDo" ng-controller="main">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <myCustomer></myCustomer>
  </body>
```

My Js code :

```
var app = angular.module('birthdayToDo', []);

app.controller('main', function($scope) {
  $scope.employees=[
                    {
                      Name:"Amit",
                      Email:"Amit@gmail.com"
                    },
                    {
                      Name:"Ajay",
                      Email:"Ajay@gmail.com"
                    },
                    {
                      Name:"Rahul",
                      Email:"Rahul@gmail.com"
                    },
                    {
                      Name:"Aakash",
                      Email:"Aakash@gmail.com"
                    },
                    {
                      Name:"Rohit",
                      Email:"Rohit@gmail.com"
                    },
                  ];

});
app.directive('myCustomer', function() {
    var directive = {};

    directive.restrict = 'E'; /* restrict this directive to elements */
    directive.templateUrl = "directiveFile.html";

    return directive;
  });
```

my **directiveFile.html** code

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>SNo.</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Email</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.Email}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But this code is not working . What's wrong I'm doing.

**[Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/2bvLGAPpekFbF6RKEUI5?p=preview)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 option of naming:

**1.**

```
app.directive('myCustomer', function()
<my-customer> </my-customer>
```

**2.**

```
app.directive('mycustomer', function()
<mycustomer>  </mycustomer>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<myCustomer></myCustomer>
```

To this:

```
<my-customer></my-customer>
```

Answer (score 2):

Directives uses snake case.

change your HTML to this

```
<my-customer></my-customer>
```

Always remember ng-app, ng-click, etc